# IoC container that doesn't require registration

Tags: dependency-injection, ioc-container

Is there such a thing?
If all I need to do is resolve **IThing** to **Thing**, why do I need to even create a registration?  I should just map dynamically during run-time.  I can easily create one with reflection..but was hoping to avoid building my own..

I am resolving like for like.  It is easy to do with reflection, without registration..

Comment: How do you expect the container to know how to resolve anything?

Comment: As the question states, the container dynamically resolves like for like.  So there should not need to be a registration.

Comment: It won't know how to resolve anything unless you tell it to.

Comment: Let's try again..You don't have to "tell" anything to a container, if it already knows to resolve using string match

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for is the concept of **Auto-Registration**. Most containers allow you to either register types in an assembly based on a *convention*, or do unregistered type resolution and find the missing type for you.

For instance, you can search through an assembly and register all types that match the convention during startup:

```cs
var container = new Container();

Assembly assembly = typeof(Thing).Assembly;

var mappings =
    from type in assembly.GetExportedTypes()
    let matchingInterface = "I" + type.Name
    let service = type.GetInterfaces().FirstOrDefault(i => matchingInterface)
    where service != null
    select new { service, type };

foreach (var mapping in mappings)
{
    // Register the type in the container
    container.Register(mapping.service, mapping.type);
}
```

Using unregistered type resolution, you can make the registration on the fly. How to do this is very much dependent on which container you use. With Simple Injector, for instance, this looks as follows:

```cs
var container = new Container();

Assembly assembly = typeof(Thing).Assembly;

container.ResolveUnregisteredType += (s, e)
{
    Type service = e.UnregisteredServiceType;
    if (service.IsInterface)
    {
         var types = (
             from type in asssembly.GetExportedTypes()
             where service.IsAssignableFrom(type)
             where !type.IsAbstract
             where service.Name == "I" + type.Name
             select type)
             .ToArray();

         if (types.Length == 1)
         {
             e.Register(Lifestyle.Transient.CreateRegistration(types[0], container));
         }          
    }
};
```

Both methods prevent you from having to update your container configuration constantly.

Comment: "unregistered type resolution" is exactly what I was looking for.  I don't want to use auto registration

Comment: Although I marked this as the accepted answer, I am still in search for a container that does not need to register anything neither at startup or dynamically.  Simply by Activator.CreateInstance(type) as described here.
https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/87b416/dynamically-create-instance-of-class-by-passing-string-as-cl/

Comment: The examples given in my answer use Simple Injector.

Comment: Refrain from creating your classes using Activator.CreateInstance, because by doing so, you are effectively building your own DI Container, which is not recommended.

Comment: hence the OQ: "IoC container that doesn't require registration"
Does one exist?

Comment: I think most, if not all, mature DI Containers in .NET support this.

Comment: Support "ResolveUsingUnregisteredType by registering at runtime??
But i am looking for one that does without ANY registration..using Activator :))
Are there ones that support that? :))